# Formattable has problems rendering special font characters

Tags: r, formatter, formattable

I am trying to build a formattable with two columns, one a metric category and the other a trend indicator. For the trend I would like to use various direction arrows using the extended characters in the loaded font set. These can be referenced using the "&#xnnnn;" notation.

However, whenever I specify a specific formatter for the trend the translation fails and the arrow character is not displayed (the string representation is!).

In the code below, the first print works (using textout1); the second fails.

```
library(formattable)

metric <- "Quality"
trend <- "&#x2191"

thetext <- data.frame("Metric" = metric, "Trend" = trend)

f1 <- formattable::formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "#0066CC", "font-family" = "Cambria"))
f2 <- formattable::formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "#00FF00", "font-family" = "Cambria",
    font.weight = "bold"))
        
textout1 <- formattable::formattable(thetext, align = c("l", "l"), list("Metric" = f1))
textout2 <- formattable::formattable(thetext, align = c("l", "l"), list("Metric" = f1, "Trend" = f2))

print (formattable(textout1))
print (formattable(textout2))
```